# How can I get WP to build a feed based on multiple taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms, feed

Currently, the best way to get a feed generated for a single taxonomy term is by letting wordpress generate the content automatically:

```
example.com/wordpress/feed?tax_slug=term_slug
```

However, is there a built in way of being able to produce a feed using multiple terms from the same taxonomy? For example:

```
example.com/wordpress/feed?tax_slug=term1,term2,term3&another_tax_slug=term4,term5
```

The idea is to use built in wordpress functionalities to generate the feed, and not have to manually create one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Query Multiple Taxonomies plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies